# Postman making JWT token request fails

Tags: python, django, jwt

I have a DRF API I'm trying to test it using postman.
But I keep failing at accessing the view.
I'm generating a token. 
But I can't figure out how the request with the token should look like.

[image: Postman]

This request returns this Django error:

[image: Error]

When using the Authorization Options in postman this happens:

[image]

My JWT auth settings:

```py
JWT_AUTH = {
    # If the secret is wrong, it will raise a jwt.DecodeError.
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    # If set to False, JWTs will last forever meaning a leaked token could be used by an attacker.
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,

    # Default is datetime.timedelta(seconds=300)(5 minutes).
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(hours=1),

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
}
```

Comment: have a look at the postman documentation on how to pass a token in the header: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/

Comment: @vctrd I did, I forgot to mention it, will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your url should be in this way:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/messages
```

You should add JWT Token as header of request:

```
Authorization: JWT <your token>
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems like the request is sent properly but this error returns now:
```{
    "detail": "Error decoding signature."
}```

Comment: You can check whether your token is valid here: https://jwt.io/

Comment: It says it's invalid but doesn;t provide any clues as to why.
I've changed the hashing default and now it's says this:
```{
    "detail": "Invalid payload."
}```

Comment: I have checked my JWT configuration and as i see `JWT_ALGORITHM`, and `JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX` were not set.